# how to pass promise to map

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise

i have a blog and i've some posts on it.
in **post** table i inserted posts with *authorId*.
and now i want to convert all *authorId* to *authorName* from another table that is called **user**.
to convert, i use a function **getPostAuthor** that returns a promise to main function.
but i can't collect returned value from **getPostAuthor** with **map** function
what is problem?

```
var db = require('../controllers/db');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient();

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/blog";
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


//#1: this function lists all posts in my blog
const list = function(req, res){
    db.find('post', {}, 10, {timeCreated: 1})
    .then(posts => {
        var promises = posts.map(post =>
            getPostAuthor(post.author)
            .then(author => author /* this value doesn't go to promises*/)
        );
        console.log(promises); //printed [Promise {<pending>}, ...]
    })
}

//#2: this function gets authorId and gives authorName
const getPostAuthor = function(authorId){
    return db.findOne('user', {_id: new ObjectId(authorId)})
    .then(author => author.name);
}

//#3: finds from db
const find = function(collection, cond = {}, limit = 0, sort = {}){
        return mongo.connect(url)
        .then(db =>
            db.collection(collection)
            .find(cond)
            .limit(limit)
            .sort(sort)
            .toArray()
        )
}


//#4: finds one from db
const findOne = function(collection, cond = {}){
        return mongo.connect(url)
        .then(db =>
            db.collection(collection).findOne(cond)
        )
}


list();
```

Comment: `.then(posts => {` isn't returning anything ... so you've built an array of promises in the variable `promises` ... and discarded it - in fact, the `list` function itself returns nothing, so, not sure what you expect from your code

Comment: you possibly need to do `Promise.all(promises).then(results => { /* do something with the resolved promises here */});`

Comment: in this step i only want print promises and see an array of authorNames

Comment: they are promises, you need to wait for them to resolve, see second comment :p

Comment: tnx, this works correctly.

Comment: I've given an alternative solution in an answer, as well as the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the promises you received using .map to resolve to see the values - like this:

```
const list = function(req, res){
    db.find('post', {}, 10, {timeCreated: 1})
    .then(posts => {
        var promises = posts.map(post =>
            getPostAuthor(post.author)
            .then(author => author /* this value doesn't go to promises*/)
        );
        console.log(promises); //printed [Promise {<pending>}, ...]
        // ********* 3 lines added to your code here
        Promise.all(promises).then(authors => {
            console.log(authors);
        });
    })
}
```

alternatively

```
const list = function(req, res){
    // added return below
    return db.find('post', {}, 10, {timeCreated: 1})
    .then(posts => {
        var promises = posts.map(post =>
            getPostAuthor(post.author)
            .then(author => author /* this value doesn't go to promises*/)
        );
        console.log(promises); //printed [Promise {<pending>}, ...]
        // *** added line below
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
}
```

...

```
list().then(authors => {
    console.log(authors);
});
```